# Email attachment with journey email send

Tags: journeybuilder

Can we send an email with attachment through journey builder ? My logic is working via email studio but not Journey Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add things like PDFs to content builder.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_upload_files.htm&type=5